# A MySql query for returning time which is greater than 22:00 and smaller than 06:00 for group of different timestamps

Tags: mysql, date, time, timestamp, datediff

I'm developing a working time registrator and I'm wondering if anybody has a simple solution for selecting "night hours" from array of timestamps, which represents the start and end of working (of course this could be overnight).

Example timestamps:

```
SELECT start, end FROM work

start                   end
2016-05-23 18:13:59     2016-05-24 02:12:45
2016-05-24 18:12:47     2016-05-25 02:13:39
2016-05-25 17:39:28     2016-05-26 01:37:35
2016-05-26 17:39:42     2016-05-27 01:39:31
2016-05-30 01:59:43     2016-05-30 10:41:37
2016-05-31 01:55:23     2016-05-31 10:49:11
2016-06-01 02:01:21     2016-06-01 12:03:13
```

I would like to return total ammount of time (in one field), which is after `22:00:00` and before `06:00:00` - so the night hours. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What is the max time period (if any) between the start and end? ie, is it possible that a time period could cover 2 or more sets of night hours?

Comment: No, maximum set of night hours is allways 1. Hope this would simplify things a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes the info from your comments under your question `maximum set of night hours is always 1. Hope this would simplify things a bit.` with a slight expansion on it below. It allows for a worker to hit as many as 3 nightly hour blocks in a 2 calendar day chunk per shift. Those are represented by 3 ranges. It can easily be expanded if the total hours worked for a shift occurs such that it traverses more than 2 calendar days. Note, however, that the last row of the sample data is a long shift of 41 hours. Just ask if needed how to expand it. But the same data shows various boundary condition tests and hopefully covers it all for now.

### Schema

```
create table times
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    startDT datetime not null,
    endDT datetime not null
);
```

### Sample Data

```
insert times(startDT,endDT) values
('2016-05-23 18:13:59','2016-05-24 02:12:45'),
('2016-05-24 18:12:47','2016-05-25 02:13:39'),
('2016-05-25 17:39:28','2016-05-26 01:37:35'),
('2016-05-26 17:39:42','2016-05-27 01:39:31'),
('2016-05-30 01:59:43','2016-05-30 10:41:37'),
('2016-05-31 01:55:23','2016-05-31 10:49:11'),
('2016-06-01 02:01:21','2016-06-01 12:03:13'),
('2016-06-01 05:30:00','2016-06-01 13:00:00'),
('2016-06-01 05:30:00','2016-06-01 22:35:00'),
('2016-06-01 05:30:00','2016-06-01 22:30:00'),
('2016-06-01 05:30:00','2016-06-02 22:30:00');
```

### Query with Debug Info shown

```
select id,startDt,endDt,
coalesce(@r1Begin:=concat(date(startDt),' 00:00:00'),null) as `@r1Begin`,
coalesce(@r1End:=concat(date(startDt),' 06:00:00'),null) as `@r1End`,
coalesce(@r2Begin:=concat(date(startDt),' 22:00:00'),null) as `@r2Begin`,
coalesce(@r2End:=concat(date(date_add(date(startDt),interval 1 day)), ' 06:00:00'),null) as `@r2End`,
coalesce(@r3Begin:=concat(date(date_add(date(startDt),interval 1 day)), ' 22:00:00'),null) as `@r3Begin`,
coalesce(@r3End:=concat(date(date_add(date(startDt),interval 1 day)), ' 23:59:59'),null) as `@r3End`,
(secondsOverlapped(startDt,endDt,@r1Begin,@r1End) + secondsOverlapped(startDt,endDt,@r2Begin,@r2End) + secondsOverlapped(startDt,endDt,@r3Begin,@r3End) ) / 3600 as graveyardHours
from times;
```

[image]

The above zoomed in to just 4 columns

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id | startDt             | endDt               | graveyardHours |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|  1 | 2016-05-23 18:13:59 | 2016-05-24 02:12:45 |         4.2125 |
|  2 | 2016-05-24 18:12:47 | 2016-05-25 02:13:39 |         4.2275 |
|  3 | 2016-05-25 17:39:28 | 2016-05-26 01:37:35 |         3.6264 |
|  4 | 2016-05-26 17:39:42 | 2016-05-27 01:39:31 |         3.6586 |
|  5 | 2016-05-30 01:59:43 | 2016-05-30 10:41:37 |         4.0047 |
|  6 | 2016-05-31 01:55:23 | 2016-05-31 10:49:11 |         4.0769 |
|  7 | 2016-06-01 02:01:21 | 2016-06-01 12:03:13 |         3.9775 |
|  8 | 2016-06-01 05:30:00 | 2016-06-01 13:00:00 |         0.5000 |
|  9 | 2016-06-01 05:30:00 | 2016-06-01 22:35:00 |         1.0833 |
| 10 | 2016-06-01 05:30:00 | 2016-06-01 22:30:00 |         1.0000 |
| 11 | 2016-06-01 05:30:00 | 2016-06-02 22:30:00 |         9.0000 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

id 11 is a 41 hour shift hitting 3 grayeyard hour segments but only accounting for 9 grayeyard hours: 1/2 hr + 8 hrs + 1/2 hr

### Final Query with 1 row, 1 column

```
select sum(graveyardShiftHoursWorked) as graveYardHours
from
(   select id,startDt,endDt,
    coalesce(@r1Begin:=concat(date(startDt),' 00:00:00'),null) as `@r1Begin`,
    coalesce(@r1End:=concat(date(startDt),' 06:00:00'),null) as `@r1End`,
    coalesce(@r2Begin:=concat(date(startDt),' 22:00:00'),null) as `@r2Begin`,
    coalesce(@r2End:=concat(date(date_add(date(startDt),interval 1 day)), ' 06:00:00'),null) as `@r2End`,
    coalesce(@r3Begin:=concat(date(date_add(date(startDt),interval 1 day)), ' 22:00:00'),null) as `@r3Begin`,
    coalesce(@r3End:=concat(date(date_add(date(startDt),interval 1 day)), ' 23:59:59'),null) as `@r3End`,
    (secondsOverlapped(startDt,endDt,@r1Begin,@r1End) + secondsOverlapped(startDt,endDt,@r2Begin,@r2End) + secondsOverlapped(startDt,endDt,@r3Begin,@r3End) ) / 3600 as graveyardShiftHoursWorked
    from times
) xDerived;

+----------------+
| graveyardHours |
+----------------+
|        39.3674 |
+----------------+
```

### Function used

The following is a user-defined function that takes a work datetime begin and end, and determines the seconds of overlap with the supplied range to compare it to. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to pretty it up such that all error traps are accounted for. For instance, if the work day range supplied has the worker's end `datetime` occurring before the start `datetime` (ie: your data is bad), etc.

Note, the function returns `seconds`. It is in the query itself that uses this function that it divides by `3600` to convert to hours.

```
drop function if exists secondsOverlapped;
DELIMITER $$
create function secondsOverlapped(r1Begin datetime,r1End datetime,r2Begin datetime,r2End datetime)
RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE beginOverride datetime;
    DECLARE endOverride datetime;
    DECLARE elapsedSeconds int; 

    IF (r1End<=r2Begin) or (r2End<=r1Begin) THEN
        return 0;
    END IF;
    set beginOverride=greatest(r1Begin,r2Begin);
    set endOverride=least(r1End,r2End);
    set elapsedSeconds=TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(endOverride,beginOverride));
    return elapsedSeconds;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Mysql manual page for [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and Least and Greatest [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: No additional comments or questions needed it works as expected. I think this is a great general solution for lots of scenarios about time calculation. Thank you!